# I want similar data when I query in realm

Tags: android, realm

I have a project I have a problem like this. I want to get similar data when I query.
How can I do that.

```
RealmResults<MyObject> list = realm.where(MyObject).equalTo("key", "13-10").findAll();
```

This is in the database: `13-10-2017`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `beginsWith(String fieldName, String value, Case casing)`

> Condition that the value of field begins with the specified substring.

Like:

```
realm.where(MyObject.class).beginsWith(yourFieldName,yourValue, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```

For more info see [here.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html)

Comment: I have a problem. When it is 14-10 it brings me on 13-10-2017. :(

Comment: @AhmetKocaman yourFieldName is the column name (key i.e 13-10-2017 is stored as String) and yourValue is the value (14-10) with which you are going to do the search. It should not return any result if your column in your case "key" does not have any value starting with String "14-10"

Comment: Brace for `why does my code show data from 2017 and 2018` :p